# Bootstrap5-Toggler Button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have used the toggler button using bootstrap 5 in the navbar but it is not displaying the navbar items that are collapsed on minimizing browser screen. Why is it not working properly? and how to resolve it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" >
        <title>
            bootstrap installation
        </title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav m-lg-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                    </li>    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                    </li>            
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you provided works fine for me. Are you sure you included the Bootstrap JS file?

Comment: No. How to add it?

Comment: It is working now after including the JS file. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works fine for me. Are you sure you included the Bootstrap JS file?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bootstrap JS CDN link, Add this inside your head element

```html
<head>
...
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```